# Doubt in proof of Theorem 3.19 from Patrick Morandi's *Field and Galois Theory*

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, splitting-field

**Relevant notations and results**

- Let $K / F$ be a field extension and let $\alpha \in K$ be algebraic over $F$. We denote the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$ by $\min(F,\alpha)$.
- If $\sigma : F \to F'$ is a field homomorphism, then there is an induced ring homomorphism $F[x] \to F'[x]$, which we also denote by $\sigma$, given by $\sigma\left( \sum a_i x^i \right) = \sum \sigma(a_i) x^i$.
- **Lemma 3.17.** *Let $\sigma : F \to F'$ be a field isomorphism. Let $f(x) \in F[x]$ be irreducible, let $\alpha$ be a root of $f$ in some extension field $K$ of $F$, and let $\alpha'$ be a root of $\sigma(f)$ in some extension $K'$ of $F'$. Then there is an isomorphism $\tau : F(\alpha) \to F'(\alpha')$ with $\tau(\alpha) = \alpha'$ and $\tau |_F = \sigma$.*

---

I am reading Patrick Morandi's *Field and Galois Theory*, and on page 34, he states and proves the following theorem, which is a special case of the Isomorphism Extension Theorem.

> **Theorem 3.19.** *Let $\sigma : F \to F'$ be a field isomorphism, let $f(x) \in F[x]$ and let $\sigma(f) \in F'[x]$ be the corresponding polynomial over $F'$. Let $K$ be a splitting field of $f$ over $F$, and let $K'$ be a splitting field of $\sigma(f)$ over $F'$. Then there is an isomorphism $\tau : K \to K'$ with $\tau|_F = \sigma$. Furthermore, if $\alpha \in K$ and if $\alpha'$ is any root of $\sigma(\min(F,\alpha))$ in $K'$, then $\tau$ can be chosen so that $\tau(\alpha) = \alpha'$.*

*Proof:* We prove this by induction on $n = [K:F]$. If $n = 1$, then $f$ splits over $F$, and the result is trivial in this case. So, suppose that $n > 1$ and that the result is true for splitting fields of degree less than $n$. $\color{red}{\text{If $f$ splits over $F$, then the result is clear.}}$ If not, let $p(x)$ be a nonlinear irreducible factor of $f(x)$, $\color{blue}{\text{let $\alpha$ be a root of $p$,}}$ and let $\alpha'$ be a root of $\sigma(p)$. Set $L = F(\alpha)$ and $L' = F'(\alpha')$. Then $[L:F] > 1$, so $[K:L] < n$. By Lemma 3.17, there is a field isomorphism $\rho : L \to L'$ with $\rho(\alpha) = \alpha'$. Since $K$ is a splitting field over $L$ for $f(x)$ and $K'$ is a splitting field over $L'$ for $\sigma(f)$, by induction the isomorphism $\rho$ extends to an isomorphism $\tau : K \to K'$. The isomorphism $\tau$ is then an extension of $\sigma$ (and $\rho$), and $\tau(\alpha) = \rho(\alpha) = \alpha'$. $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

---

My doubts are related to the highlighted parts in the proof:

1. Upon assuming that $n = [K:F] > 1$, it is certain that $f$ cannot split over $F$, because then we would have $K = F \implies [K:F] = 1$. So, isn't the statement highlighted in red redundant?
2. In the proof, $\alpha$ is taken to be a root of (an irreducible factor of) $f$, and $\alpha'$ a root of the corresponding polynomial. But in the statement of the theorem $\alpha$ is an arbitrary element of $K$. It doesn't seem to be obvious how to use the given proof to construct an isomorphism $K \to K'$ which sends this arbitrary $\alpha$ to an $\alpha'$. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof is a little jumbled up. It is true that the sentence highlighted in red is redundant. Moreover, in the proof the author seems to be showing the existence of an isomorphism $\tau : K \to K'$ with $\tau |_F = \sigma$, which only incidentally maps a root of an irreducible factor $p$ of $f$ to a root of $\sigma(p)$. The latter half of the theorem still needs proof.

To correct/complete the proof, we can work in the following manner.

---

If $n = 1$, then $f$ splits over $F$, and the result is trivial in this case. So, suppose that $n > 1$ and that the result is true for splitting fields of degree less than $n$.

Let $\alpha \in K$ and $p = \min(F,\alpha)$. Suppose that $\deg(p) > 1$. Let $\alpha' \in K'$ be a root of $\sigma(p)$. Set $L = F(\alpha)$ and $L' = F'(\alpha')$. Then, $[L:F] > 1$, so $[K:L] < n$. By Lemma 3.17, there is a field isomorphism $\rho : L \to L'$ with $\rho(\alpha) = \alpha'$ and $\rho |_F = \sigma$. Since $K$ is a splitting field over $L$ for $f(x)$ and $K'$ is a splitting field over $L'$ for $\sigma(f)$, by induction the isomorphism $\rho$ extends to an isomorphism $\tau : K \to K'$. The isomorphism $\tau$ is then an extension of $\sigma$ (and $\rho$), and $\tau(\alpha) = \rho(\alpha) = \alpha'$.

And, what if $\deg(p) = 1$? Then, $\alpha \in F$, $p = x - \alpha$ and $\sigma(p) = x - \sigma(\alpha)$, so $\alpha' = \sigma(\alpha)$. So, any isomorphism $\tau : K \to K'$ with $\tau |_F = \sigma$ will satisfy $\tau(\alpha) = \alpha'$. So, if $\alpha \in K$ is such that $\deg(\min(F,\alpha)) = 1$, then we only need to show the existence of an isomorphism $\tau : K \to K'$ with $\tau |_F = \sigma$ to complete the proof. But this is the content of the proof as given in the textbook, so we are done.

---

Incidentally, the proof of Theorem 3.20 (Isomorphism Extension Theorem), given in the textbook on pages 34-35, also suffers from the same flaw. There, too, the author constructs an isomorphism $\tau : K \to K'$ of splitting fields that extends the isomorphism $\sigma : F \to F'$ of the base fields, but neglects to prove that $\tau$ can be chosen so that $\tau(\alpha) = \alpha'$, where $\alpha \in K$ and $\alpha'$ is any root of $\sigma(\min(F,\alpha))$. A similar argument as above can complete that proof as well.